# How to display one variable values in three seperate columns using My SQL queries

Tags: mysql

I have a column name 'pressure' which has three values (high, low, normal).

Now I want to show the sum of high, low and normal in three separate  columns.

```html
Desired output
----------------------
pressure:   high    low   Normal
Number:      ?       ?     ?
```

Can some please suggest.

Comment: Google "SQL pivot query" to get started.

Comment: Please define: "normal". Do you mean the arithmetic-mean, modal value, or median? Or some other value, such as a 95%-percentile bound?

Comment: Thank very much. I have a column name 'pressure' which has values (high, low, normal). Now I wanted to count these three values and put it in the separate columns. Kindly suggest SQL query.

Comment: Hope, I am describing my query clearly

Comment: @awan No, you aren't describing your problem clearly because you still haven't posted your original query or described how your `JOIN` works (and why you're using a `JOIN` in the first place when it looks like you only have a single table with scalar values to work with)

Comment: Hi Tim and Dai, Thank you very much for your prompt reply. I found the solution of my query: (part I)
select sum(high) as high1, sum(low) as low1, sum(normal) as normal1 from (
select a2.pressure, a2.countwp, b.high,c.low,d.normal from (
select a1.pressure, a1.countwp, b.high, c.low from (
select a.pressure, a.countwp, b.high from (

select  pressure, count (pressure) as countwp from t1 group by pressure) as a
LEFT  JOIN
(select  pressure, count (pressure) as high from t1  where pressure='High' group by pressure) as b ON a.pressure=b.pressure) as a1

Comment: LEFT JOIN
(select  pressure, count (pressure) as low from t1  where pressure='Low' group by pressure) as c ON a1.pressure=c.pressure) as a2
LEFT JOIN
(select  pressure, count (pressure) as normal from t1  where pressure='Normal' group by pressure) as d ON a2.pressure=d.pressure) as e

Comment: @Dai, As per your I have edited my query. Please don't forget to lift out the 'negative' marking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a query like this:

```
SELECT
    SampleDateTime,    -- datetimeoffset(7) NOT NULL
    Celsius            -- float             NOT NULL
FROM
    Temperatures
ORDER BY
    SampleDateTime
```

Then you can do this:

```
SELECT
    MAX( Celsius ) AS [High],
    MIN( Celsius ) AS [Low],
    AVG( Celsius ) AS [Mean],
    PERCENTILE_CONT( 0.5 ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY Celsius ) OVER () AS [Median]
FROM
    Temperatures
```

If you want the modal-value, that's a bit more involved. As this is probably continuous data you'll need to `ROUND` it to get discrete values

```
SELECT
    TOP 1
    ROUND( Celsius, 0 ) AS [Mode]
FROM
    Temperatures
GROUP BY
    Celsius
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC
```

...which can be joined using a `CROSS JOIN` which is okay as each sub-query only returns a single row:

```
SELECT
    [High],
    [Low],
    [Mean],
    [Median],
    [Mode]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            MAX( Celsius ) AS [High],
            MIN( Celsius ) AS [Low],
            AVG( Celsius ) AS [Mean],
            PERCENTILE_CONT( 0.5 ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY Celsius ) OVER () AS [Median]
        FROM
        Temperatures
    ) AS t1
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            TOP 1
            ROUND( Celsius, 0 ) AS [Mode]
        FROM
            Temperatures
        GROUP BY
            Celsius
        ORDER BY
            COUNT(*) DESC
    ) AS t2
```

Comment: Thank you again for reply. My column name 'pressure' has text values (high, low, normal). Now I wanted to column them seperately and show in my sql query. For example:  id wpressure
1 high
2 low
3 normal
4 high
5 normal
6 high ,  Now I wanted to show like:   High low normal
3 2 2

Comment: @awan Your original posting made no mention of your source data design or text columns. Please edit your original question.

Answer (score 0):

With a table schema like this (including sample data):

```
create table pressure(name varchar(10), pressure varchar(10));

insert into pressure(name, pressure) values("john", "high");
insert into pressure(name, pressure) values("john", "low");
insert into pressure(name, pressure) values("john", "normal");
insert into pressure(name, pressure) values("jacob", "high");
insert into pressure(name, pressure) values("smith", "normal");
```

one way would be to query something like this:

```
select 'pressure' as data, (select count(*) from pressure where pressure = 'high') as high, (select count(*) low from pressure where pressure = 'low') as low, (select count(*) normal from pressure where pressure = 'normal') as normal from dual;
```

this should result in something like this:

```
|   data   | high | low | normal |
| pressure |   2  |  1  |    2   |
```

disclaimer: this might not scale well for huge volumes of data

Comment: @Dear KoderJ, Thanks a lot. Its work well and much simpler than the query I posted earlier. Great help. Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something along these lines

```
select 'pressure' as data, 
sum(case when pressure='high' then 1 else 0 end) as high,
sum(case when pressure='low' then 1 else 0 end) as low,
sum(case when pressure='normal' then 1 else 0 end) as normal
from your_table
```